# No mostrar teclado virtual android al cliquear un input

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Tengo una web que se muestra en un WebView android. Tengo mi propio teclado maquetado en HTML y CSS y quiero usar solo ese. Entonces, necesito que al cliquear un input, **este input permanezca en focus, pero que el teclado virtual del celular no aparezca**. ¿Hay alguna manera de lograrlo? O en todo caso, **¿hay alguna manera para deshabilitar SIEMPRE el teclado virtual sin importar si se presiona un input o no?**

Comment: Hola @Cristian. Favor de evitar comportamiento inadecuado. Según los comentarios, no eres nuevo en la comunidad, así que al igual que todos debes seguir las normas mínimas de respeto a los usuarios de la comunidad. Si los comentarios, preguntas duplicadas o etc no te ayudan, puedes reportar tu propia pregunta y en la última opción detallar el problema que tienes, un moderador lo revisará y verá la manera de resolverlo p.e. si la pregunta fue cerrada injustamente.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer esto solo debes de entrar al android manifest y hacer lo siguiente:

En la parte de activity name pon lo siguiente:

```
<activity android:name="NombreActividad"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

Y listo con esto has ocultado o deshabilitado el teclado virtual de android

Comment: Lo he hecho con anterioridad a eso, pero no me ha funcionado. Al cliquear el input se abre el teclado automáticamente. He leido posts por dos días que hablar de medir el tamaño del viewport (no puedo por usar fullscreen) o sacarle el focus al elemento (lo cual tampoco me sirve porque es un chat lo que estoy haciendo). ¿Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a forzar su ocultación:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Con esto debería de quedar oculto el teclado virtual.